# Liquibase/Oracle: Copy value from one table to another in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I have two tables `parent` and `child` with a one-to-many relation. I have a value in the child table that is always the same for a given parent ID. Therefore, I want to copy the value to a newly created column in the parent table.

| PARENT_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |

| CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VALUE_1 |
| 2 | 1 | VALUE_1 |
| 3 | 1 | VALUE_1 |
| 4 | 2 | VALUE_2 |
| 5 | 2 | VALUE_2 |

I am using Liquibase and looking for a solution that works with Oracle and H2 (in Oracle mode).

This gives me a syntax error but the nested SELECT works:

```
UPDATE (SELECT DISTINCT PARENT.PARENT_ID, CHILD.VALUE as OLD_COLUMN, PARENT.VALUE as NEW_COLUMN
FROM PARENT
LEFT JOIN CHILD
ON PARENT.PARENT_ID = CHILD.PARENT_ID) t
SET t.NEW_COLUMN = t.OLD_COLUMN;
```

Output of nested SELECT:

| PARENT_ID | OLD_COLUMN | NEW_COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VALUE_1 | null |
| 2 | VALUE_2 | null |

It doesn't have to be a SQL solution, a Liquibase Update would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sql will achieve what you are looking for:

```
update parent p
  set value = (select distinct value 
                 from child c 
                where c.parent_id = p.parent_id);
```